# How to specify the arguments' order with getopts function?

Tags: bash, getopts

```
test-fun(){    
    OPTIND=1
    while  getopts  "waz" arg
    do
        case  $arg  in
            w)
                 echo  "ok w"
                ;;
            a)
                echo  "ok a"
                ;;
            z)
                echo  "ok z"
                ;;   
        esac
    done
}
```

For the above test-fun, `test-fun  -wz` result in

```
ok w
ok z
```

`test-fun  -zw` result in

```
ok z
ok w
```

I want to specify the arguments' order  for test-fun function,all arguments in the order `w` `a` `z`,if you input `test-fun zw`,an error occur `wrong arguments' order for the function`,how to fix it?

Comment: Why should the order of the optional arguments matter?

Comment: The arguments' order contain some useful info for my real function.

Comment: That makes me wonder how optional they actually are, and whether you should just be using positional parameters instead.

Comment: Or rather, what does `zw` tell you that is different from `wz` if `wz` isn't allowed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Put the arguments in a variable with line feeds (vars), sort it and then process the new variable (vars1).

```
test-fun(){    
OPTIND=1
while  getopts  "waz" arg
do
    vars=$vars"\n"$arg
done
vars1=$(printf $vars | sort)
for i in $vars1

do
    case  $arg  in
        w)
             echo  "ok w"
            ;;
        a)
            echo  "ok a"
            ;;
        z)
            echo  "ok z"
            ;;   
    esac
done
}
```